# Detecting Type of Video Stream

Tags: python, bash, streaming, video-streaming, multimedia

I have 2 video streams

(1) VLC Generated Compressed MP4 UDP stream

(2) DV Uncompressed UDP Stream

Both are destined to a host. At this Unix receiving host, I would like to detect type of stream coming using Bash or Python Scripting (without tcpdump, I do not have root priv.)

ANY idea guys how to implement ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what about trying pyffmpeg out. you should be able to get the container info from that.

Comment: Thanks. But in this case I think, I would have to install ffmpeg on the receiving host. Isn't ?

Comment: You wouldn't need to install it, just compile the binary and execute if from its source directory.